# Find number of words before a string

Tags: r, text, nlp

In a given text, how can I find the number of words preceding a string?

For example: `"how to format this article? put return between paragraphs'`

I wish to determine that `'put return between paragraphs'` starts from the 6th word or, in other words, that there are 5 words before it.

Alternatively, is there a way to take into account customized tokens during tokenization such that I can treat `'put return between paragraphs'` as one token and the rest of individual words as a token each?

Update: This has nothing to do with newline.

Comment: Is the sixth word really a meaningful thing here?  Isn't the question mark the actual marker which triggers a newline?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to add a newline after five words, you may use `sub` as follows:

```
x <- "how to format this article? put return between paragraphs"
sub("^((?:\\S+\\s+){5})", "\\1\n", x)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming `s` is your string above, you could go for

```
library(stringi)
parts <- unlist(stri_split(s, regex = "[\\?\\.\\!]"))
stri_count(parts[1], regex = " ")+1 # 5
```

(and possibly generalize the logic)